# Uniformly Most Powerful Test for Normal variance

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be a random sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Derive Uniformly Most Powerful test for $H_0: \sigma^2 \leq1$ vs $H_a: \sigma^2 \geq 2$.

I have been studying for qualifying exam and came across this problem. Since normal distribution has monotone likelihood property it can be easily shown that $H_0: \sigma^2 \leq1$ vs $H_a: \sigma^2 > 1$ is UMP by Karlin Rubin theorem.

But I could not derive UMP for $H_0: \sigma^2 \leq1$ vs $H_a: \sigma^2 \geq 2$.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The null hypothesis is still of the form $\sigma^2 \le 1$ while the alternative hypothesis is still of the form "population variance is big" in both cases, so why do think this might change the test for a given size?

Comment: Thanks Henry. I am not quite sure. Should the test be the same for both the cases?

Comment: I would have thought so.  For example the power for $\sigma^2=4$ or whatever should be the same

Comment: How should I show that testing $H _0: \sigma^2 \leq 1$ vs $H _0: \sigma^2 \geq 2$ is same as testing $H _0: \sigma^2 \leq 1$ vs $H _0: \sigma^2 > 1$?